# WMI winmgmts \\.root\cimv2 invalid access to memory location

Tags: wmi, windows-10, winpe

I am trying to create an object using GetObject("winmgmts:\.root\cimv2") and I get invalid access to memory location message. Any suggestion?

the script runs fine in Main Windows OS environment however the same script fails from windows recovery environment.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Recovery Environment is using WinPE.  WinPE does not natively have WMI support in it.  You could update that environment to support WMI.

You probably would need to install "WinPE-WMI.cab"

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824926.aspx

This article's instructions would be pertinent to any of the newer Windows 8,8.1,10